# jackson ObjectMapper writeValueAsString() always returns null

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm working with legacy code and have to use jmockit to make a few new tests. I've been trying for several hours to test that the result of writeValueAsString() matches what it is supposed to. No matter what the object is that is being passed in to ObjectMapper, it always returns null. I've tried every variation I can think of. Below is the simplest case that reproduces the issue. We are using jackson 2.6.x. writeValueAsString() works fine in production but for some reason always returns null under test.

```
@Test
public void test_method(){
   Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
   user.put("userId", "someValidUserId");
   user.put("accessToken", "someValidAccessToken");

   String outJson ="";
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   try {
       outJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(user); // outJson is always null. Why?
       System.out.println(outJson);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println(e);
   }
}
```

Comment: It's working just fine with jackson 2.6.5 on my machine.

Comment: Maybe it is a bug in intellij 2017.1? I'll try running it outside of Intellij

Comment: Might be, I'm using 2016.3.1.